# Stepper Motor Driver CLK-IN vs Parallel-IN

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, driver, motor-controller

I have a few questions about stepper motor drivers. I'm currently trying to build a PCB with a stepper motor driver IC to gain a better understanding of them. Here is the link to the IC I'm using: https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/motor/stepper/bd6383efv-e.pdf.

I noticed the datasheet mentioned a CLK-IN mode and a PARA-IN mode. From my understanding, CLK-IN uses a CLK signal and moves the stepper motor a portion of a step for each rising edge of the function. What is the PARA-IN mode? Also, I noticed the datasheet recommended using a resistor to set the PWM frequency. Which PWM frequency does this refer to? Does this need to match the frequency of my CLK? Thank you!

Comment: (1) Your link is to a tech note, not the datasheet.  Can you give me ***the link to the datasheet?***

Comment: Hi, the model number is BD6387EFV. The document appears under datasheet on their website and I don't see any other documents that would be useful. Is there any particular information that is missing?

Comment: Well, I asked because I googled hard but every time ended up disappointment, every  time ending up to your ***tech note***, not the datasheet.  Can you give me **the exact link to the datasheet**?